# working with a command prompt to execute a java program

Tags: java, command-line, program-entry-point

i have a program that is read from file , and store the content in a linked list then write the content of the linked list to another file ,

I have three classes : 
1- Agent( main class ) 
2- State
3- LinkedList

the content of the calss Agent is :

```
public class Agent{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int n_args = args.length;
        if (n_args!=4) {
            System.out.println("ERROR: ILLEGAL NUMBER OF ARGUMENTS.");
            System.out.println("Number of arguments must be 4");
            return;
        }
        String mapFile = args[0];
        String commandsFile = args[1];
        String finalMapFile = args[2];
        String logFile = args[3];

        State s = new State();
        s.read(args[0]);
        s.read2(args[1]);
        s.Action();
        s.writemap(args[2]);
        s.write(args[3]);


    }



}
```

- all the method that i need them are in class State
  so i created a object of State
  then i did all the work
  but the problem is when i execute it from command prompt when i write this :

  C:\Users\prof\Desktop\Compilation>javac Agent.java

  i get this message :

Agent.java:27: error: unreported exception IOException; must be caught or declared to be thrown

```
                    s.read(args[0]);
                          ^
    Agent.java:28: error: unreported exception IOException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
                    s.read2(args[1]);
                           ^
    Agent.java:30: error: unreported exception UnsupportedEncodingException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
                s.writemap(args[2]);
                          ^
    Agent.java:31: error: unreported exception UnsupportedEncodingException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
                s.write(args[3]);
                       ^
    4 errors
```

i want my program work as the following :

```
  java Agent mapFile.txt commandsLine.txt finalMap.txt logFile.txt
```

any help ?

Comment: Do you understand the difference between `compiling` and `executing`? Your program currently does not compile and the error message is telling you why.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with the command line nor what you are trying to do.
There is an error in your code: you are not catching exceptions.

Least of it, you should wrap your `main()` content in a `try-catch` block.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/try.html

Comment: my code work well when i'm executing it from eclipse , but i don't how to  work with it through a command prompt

Comment: does it still run in eclipse if you clean your project?